# I want to store excel in database having data in 3 sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, data-storage

I want to store excel file in SQL Server database having 3 sheets.
So what will be better option form following.

1st Option Creating 3 table for each sheet and saving data.

2nd Appending columns to single table and append sheetnumber as prefix to columns

3rd convert all column data in one string (comma saperated) and store in single column

Which will be better option form above with respect to flexibility of data storage and access, space require for storing etc.

If any other option is there please tell me

Sheet3 data will be redundant for all rows. means the data in 1st row of sheet3 and last row of sheet 3 will be same in most cases

Sheet1 Sheet2 and Sheet3 data will have logical connection (not excel formula)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the most flexibility, maintainability and least chance for headaches in the future do yourself a favor and create separate tables for each sheet.

Comment: My sheet3 data will be redundant for all rows. means the data in 1st row of sheet3 and last row of sheet 3 will be same in most cases

Comment: I agree with @user3798397. One table for each sheet. If there is redundant data then you can simply replicate that in a `view` without storing the redundant data in a `table`. This option yields the best flexibility, speed, and the least amount in storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think mix 2-3 way will be better option.
The data which you need to access frequently you can store in column and the data which is not frequent useful you can store in single column like by using JSON  or comma saperated data etc.

Comment: The OP wants to optimize for flexibility, data storage, and data access. Yet, you are offering to save in comma-separated values or even (worse) JSON format. Both would require additional storage space to save the commas or additional formatting for JSON. Neither would allow a direct select as SQL would not recognize the data stored in these columns. Hence, data access would be also more difficult. So, could you please elaborate why you are even considering these options?